# How to set up a FitNesse suite hierarchy that allows for multiple "SuiteSetUp"?

Tags: testing, fitnesse

I currently have the following structure for my suite:

- OuterSuite

  - SuiteSetUp
  - InnerSuite1

    - SuiteSetUp
    - Test1
    - Test2
    - Test3
    - SuiteTearDown
  - InnerSuite2

    - SuiteSetUp
    - Test1
    - Test2
    - Test3
    - SuiteTearDown

I would like to have OuterSuite.SuiteSetUp load up a database with some basic test data. Each of InnerSuite1.SuiteSetUp and InnerSuite2.SuiteSetUp would then slightly modify the test data slightly for their respective groups of tests. (And restore it to the starting values in the respective SuiteTearDown.)

But as I have found out, "There can be only one!" SuiteSetUp. How would you go about to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

We solved a similar problem by leveraging Hudson to run specific suites for specific purposes.

It works a little like this:

1. We have a BootStrap page that we run to prepare the database.  This runs as a separate Hudson job.  This job prepares the database and then backs it up.
2. Then when we run our suites, we do a restore of the database before each suite.
3. After the database is restored, run a suite.  We run major suites separately to force the database clean as we cannot support DB rollbacks right now.

This approach isn't perfect, but it lets us manage the database better.

Answer (score 0):

You could have that kind of structure with this trick.

Content of InnerSuite#.SuiteSetUp

```
 !include -c <OuterSuite.SuiteSetUp
 # Your original code of the suite setup
```

With this flow, the SuiteSetUp of the OuterSuite will be run first and the rest of the content will be run afterwards.

This structure could be used in SuiteTearDown as well, but it could be smart to reverse the order. This could e.g. be used when removing rows that have foreign keys connected to rows that will be deleted in the outer tear down.

Content of InnerSuite#.SuiteTearDown

```
 # Your original code of the suite teardown
 !include -c <OuterSuite.SuiteTearDown
```

Comment: Hi, first of all sorry, I didn't notice this answer until now. If I were to run OuterSuite directly, wouldn't OuterSuite.SuiteSetUp then be run twice?

Comment: @EmilBadh:  The easiest way around your problem is to rename the OuterSuite.SuiteSetUp page to something else and make sure its page type property is set to static page.  Then add an include directive to the SuiteSetUp pages of InnerSuite1 and 2, pointing to the newly renamed page.  If the common setup page is not called SuiteSetUp then FitNesse won't run it automatically as part of a suite; it will only be run as part of the SuiteSetUp pages of InnerSuite1 and 2 because it is included in those pages.